# Sum of specific values in same column SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ID Date       Zone  Group destination  start            end                    sec     step   unit
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  2020-01-25 Zone1 GP1   D1         2020-01-25 08:18   2020-01-25 08:22       240      E      18
1  2020-01-25 Zone2 GP2   D1         2020-01-25 08:22   2020-01-25 08:23       70       N1     22
1  2020-01-25 Zone1 GP1   D1         2020-01-25 16:08   2020-01-25 16:58       3037     N2     25
1  2020-01-25 Zone3 GP3   D1         2020-01-25 14:18   2020-01-25 14:22        198      P      50
1  2020-01-25 Zone4 GP4   D1         2020-01-25 20:04   2020-01-25 20:09        283      D      55
1  2020-01-25 Zone3 GP3   D1         2020-01-25 08:18  2020-01-25 08:22         740      E      22
1  2020-03-10 Zone4 GP4   D1         2020-03-10 16:35  2020-03-10 16:43         459      E      789
1  2020-03-10 Zone4 GP4   D1         2020-03-10 10:43 2020-03-10 10:57          853      E      289
2  2020-03-13 Zone1 GP1   D1         2020-03-13 08:08 2020-03-13 08:11          201      N      555 
2  2020-03-13 Zone2 Gp2   D1         2020-03-13 06:27 2020-03-13 06:40          767      E      789
2  2020-03-13 Zone3 GP3   D1         2020-03-13 21:02 2020-03-13 21:09          409      E      552
2  2020-03-13 Zone4 GP4   D1         2020-03-13 21:09 2020-03-13 21:10          78       E      253
```

Above is my Sample Data I need to sum_of_individual_time and Sum of Total time

Need a Query Using the below formula.

Sum of Total time means sum of the sec value per day

sum_of_individual_time  sum of the sec where step='E' per day

sum_of_individual_time (step=E)  for 2020-01-25 of ID 1  =240+740=980

sum_of_individual_time (step=E) for 2020-03-10 of Id 1   = 459+853=1312

sum_of_individual_time (step=E) for 2020-03-13 of Id 2   = 789+552+253=1594

Sum of Total time (All steps) for 2020-01-25 of Id 1      =240+70+3037+198+283+740=4568

the sum of Total time(All steps)  for Id 1 of date 2020-03-10 = 1312

sum_of_individual_time (step=E)  for Id 1 of date 2020-03-10 = 1312

Sum of Total time (All steps)  for Id 2 of date 2020-03-13 = 555+789+552+253=2149

OUTPUT

```
ID Date Zone Group destination start end    sec     step   unit  sum of individual time   Sum of total
1  2020-01-25 Zone1 GP1 D1  2020-01-25 08:18 2020-01-25 08:22 240  E 18  980 4568
1  2020-01-25 Zone2 GP2 D1 2020-01-25 08:22 2020-01-25 08:23 70   N1 22   NULL  4568
1  2020-01-25 Zone1 GP1 D1 2020-01-25 16:08 2020-01-25 16:58 3037 N2 25   NULL  4568
1  2020-01-25 Zone3 GP3  D1 2020-01-25 14:18 2020-01-25 14:22 198  P  50  NULL  4568

1  2020-01-25 Zone4 GP4 D1  2020-01-25 20:04 2020-01-25 20:09 283   D   55   NULL  4568
1  2020-01-25 Zone3 GP3 D1 2020-01-25 08:18 2020-01-25 08:22 740 E  22  980   4568
1  2020-03-10 Zone4  GP4  D1 2020-03-10 16:35 2020-03-10 16:43  459  E  789  1312  1312
1  2020-03-10 Zone4 GP4  D1 2020-03-10 10:43 2020-03-10 10:57 853  E    289  1312   1312
2  2020-03-13 Zone1 GP1 D1 2020-03-13 08:08 2020-03-13 08:11 201 N    555    NULL  2149
2  2020-03-13 Zone2  Gp2   D1  2020-03-13 06:27 2020-03-13 06:40  767  E  789  1594  2149
2  2020-03-13 Zone3  GP3  D1 2020-03-13 21:02 2020-03-13 21:09 409 E   552  1594   2149
2  2020-03-13 Zone4 GP4  D1 2020-03-13 21:09  2020-03-13 21:10  78  E   253   1594  2149
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually need window functions to achieve what you want.

```
SELECT ID,Date,Zone,[Group],destination,[start],[end],sec,step,unit
,CASE WHEN step='E' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN step='E' THEN sec ELSE 0 END )OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) ELSE NULL END as [Sum of individual time ]
,SUM(sec) OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as [Sum of total]
From Test
```

In your example you made an error:

"Sum of Total time (All steps) for Id 2 of date 2020-03-13 = 55+789+552+253=2149" - here you summed unit not sec.

You can tell that is summing all of the day by looking at the partitioning which is PARTITION BY Date.

Here's the SQL fiddle if you want to play with it:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/125d2/1

Comment: It getting overall sum(Sec) of that ID but I need sum(sec) of that Id per day @Gabriel Durac

Comment: it does exactly what you asked for. In your example you made an error:

"Sum of Total time (All steps) for Id 2 of date 2020-03-13 = 555+789+552+253=2149" - 
here you summed unit not sec. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get that by using `group by` and `join`.

Please see the demo **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=63863140bad97395e3b91c38a8b114c6)**.

Also, your following calculations seem wrong:

sum_of_individual_time (step=E) for 2020-03-13 of Id 2 = 789+552+253=1594

sum of Total time (All steps) for Id 2 of date 2020-03-13 = 555+789+552+253=2149

**it should be**

sum_of_individual_time (step=E) for 2020-03-13 of Id 2 = 767+409+78=1254

sum of Total time (All steps) for Id 2 of date 2020-03-13 = 201+767+409+78=1455

Answer (score 0):

Use the `GROUP BY` statement and `SUM` function.

[GROUP BY docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#group-by-)

[SUM docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#a-using-sum-to-return-summary-data)